# Verbose with a positive connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

> She had given me such a _______ (verbose?) reply that I could not not helped her.

Comment: Please [look up the word in a thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/verbose?s=t) and say what alternatives you found, what you rejected and why you rejected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thorough, detailed, loquacious, exuberant, lavish, extensive

Comment: Thanks! That's quite a thorough, detailed, loquacious, exuberant, lavish, extensive answer :)