# Word for "wordy but needed" i.e. very descriptive but not verbose

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means very wordy, but with a connotation opposite that of "verbose"

For example, the documentation was easy to follow, but ___ where it needed to be

Best I could come up with is descriptive. Any ideas on a better word?

Comment: For reference, there was an earlier similar question but it was closed. There is one answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438565/verbose-with-a-positive-connotation

Answer (score 1):

You can say

> The documentation was easy to follow, but **comprehensive** where it needed to be.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/comprehensive) has

> **comprehensive**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1** Including or dealing with all or nearly all elements or aspects of something.

Answer (score 0):

***Thorough*** or ***exhaustive***.

***Thorough*** means

> complete with regard to every detail; not superficial or partial; performed or written with great care and completeness. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=thorough%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsadxntMr0iT3_DCef75zwcKsMMWGQ%3A1659981402501&ei=Wk7xYuKbHpH4gQadqr3gDA&oq=thorough%20mw&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQHhAWEAoyCggAEB4QDxAWEAoyCAgAEB4QFhAKMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6BAgjECc6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QsQMQgwEQ1AI6BAgAEEM6BQgAEJECOggILhCABBCxAzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgoILhCxAxDUAhBDOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoICAAQsQMQkQI6CgguELEDEIMBEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6DQguEIAEEMcBEK8BEAo6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsILhCABBCxAxDUAjoLCAAQsQMQgwEQkQI6DQgAEIAEELEDEEYQ-QE6BQgAEIAEOgoIABCABBBGEPkBOgQIABAKSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUABY6xRgwSJoAHABeACAAZYBiAGqCpIBBDEuMTCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

***Exhaustive*** is quite similar but an inch more intense, like nothing is left out, nothing else can be added on the subject. It means:

> including or considering all elements or aspects; fully comprehensive. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=exhaustive%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYXdVNkbnJ1ajUWYYONGkCrNrGqXQ%3A1659981859269&ei=I1DxYpiFEIakgQabiaiwAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjYorio6rf5AhUGUsAKHZsEChYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=exhaustive%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEIAEELEDMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgUIABCABDoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFD5C1ivHGDFHmgCcAF4AIABZogBoweSAQQxMC4xmAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))
>
> - an ***exhaustive*** study of the tax law ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exhaustive))